# adding tomcat to templates in intellij

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

as part of instructions to run an open source code they said to use tomcat

I installed tomcat but it is still does not show.

[image]

how can I add it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do that

1- Click on Maven Setting

[image]

2- click on Plugins

[image]

3- type tomcat and choose Smart Tomcat

[image]

4- it is there

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using IntelliJ IDEA Community edition, while Tomcat support [is the feature of IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).